# Can I write where condition on any column of table in DynamoDB

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I'm able to write where condition only on primary key but not on the other attributes in DynamoDB.
Is it possible to query data on any column in DynamoDB? If yes how ?
I'm using PHP.

Comment: _If yes, how?_ Those aren't the sort of questions expected here... Try yourself, then ask a question when you get stuck

Comment: @JustCarty I already have written I tried but I'm able to write conditions only with primary key or with combination of primary key and Hash key.
If you think this is very simple question please answer.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma show your attempt, just typing "I tried" is meaningless to us, and does not help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other attributes you use SCAN, not query and filter it by 'FilterExpression'. Here is how to do it in PHP: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.04.html

Comment: SCAN and FilterExpression solved my purpose.